# Integration tests with WebApplicationFactory in dotnet6

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have a class `public class CustomWebApplicationFactory : WebApplicationFactory<Startup>` that have a method

```
protected override IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder()
    {
        return base.CreateHostBuilder().UseEnvironment("Development").UseLogDefaults();
    }
```

After deleting from `Program.cs` this code

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseServiceProviderFactory(new AutofacServiceProviderFactory())
                .ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, config) =>
                {
                    var builtConfig = config.Build();
                    /*code here*/
                })
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder => { webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>(); });
```

The `CreateHostBuilder` method started to throw a null reference exception.
If I delete `CreateHostBuilder` override method then in tests appears an exception
`The entry point exited without ever building an IHost.`

Moving the code from `Program` to `CreateHostBuilder` did not help.
`Startup` class is untoched, only deleting `IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder` causes the error

Comment: `CreateHostBuilder()` returns null when using top-level programs (https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/29e093cf1b89e2b43b4dc752ff52c50cf8ec4996/src/Mvc/Mvc.Testing/src/WebApplicationFactory.cs#L392-L398). You need to use `ConfigureWebHost()` instead.

Comment: I'm using `ConfigureWebHost` and setup is the same as OP. Same error. Did you ever solve this?

Comment: @span Yes. You should override `CreateHost` instead of `CreateHostBuilder`, if you have similar code

Comment: @RheinmetallSkorpion Same problem. I tried that and still get the error. Maybe you could please show us that code?

Comment: @span Same problem. Do you have working code?

Comment: @MartinCostello to be more precise, `CreateHostBuilder()` returns null when using the new [`WebApplicationBuilder`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.webapplicationbuilder) class, even if you put it in the old style `Program.cs` and `Main` method.